# xsl: how to count the number of items for which there is no more than n number of children

Tags: xml, xslt

xml file:

```
<faculty>
<student name="a a" group="5">
    <subject date="2013-02-01" name="science">124</subject>
</student>

<student name="q q" group="9">
    <subject date="2013-02-01" name="my">124</subject>
</student>

<student name="z z" group="2">
</student>

<student name="v v" group="9">
    <subject date="2013-02-01" name="tro">tro</subject>
</student>
</faculty>
```

need: how to count the number of items for which there is no more than 2 subjects.

I know how to display all of these items and the number of subjects but I do not know how to count the total number of subjects:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

<xsl:key name="name" match="subject" use="@name" />

<xsl:template match="subject">
    <xsl:if test="count(key('name', @name)) &lt; 2">
        subject: <xsl:value-of select="@name" />
        count: <xsl:value-of select="count(key('name', @name))" />
    </xsl:if>
</xsl:template>
```

thanks in advance

Comment: When you say "items", do you mean that you want to know how many `student` elements have less than 2 `subject` children elements?

Comment: Do you need to list all unique subjects names which just occur once?

Answer (score 2):

The following will match the `student` elements that have less than 2 `subject` element children:

```
student[count(subject) &lt; 2]
```

If you wanted the total number of `subject` elements in the document, use the following:

```
count(/faculty/student/subject)
```

If you wanted the count of the list of distinct `@name` values from `subject` elements:

```
count(/faculty/student/subject[generate-id()=generate-id(key('name', @name)[1])])
```

Answer (score 1):

If I try to follow your questions:

**Q1:** "*How to count the number of items for which there is no more than n number of children*"

This would be: `count(items[count(*) &lt= $n ])`

**Q2:**  "*How to count the number of items for which there is no more than 2 subjects.*"

It's not really clear from your example XML and xslt what "items" should be. My interpretation is that this should be subject name.
Than: To count subject names which not occur more than 2 times try this:

```
count(//subject[
         generate-id()=generate-id(key('name', @name)[1]) 
         and 
         count(key('name', @name) ) &lt;= 2  
       ] )
```

Answer (score 0):

If you just need to display `subject` elements which occurs only once, notice the `and count(key('subject-name', @name)) = 1` part below:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
    <xsl:key name="subject-name" match="subject" use="@name" />
    <xsl:template match="faculty">
        <xsl:for-each select=".//subject[count(. | key('subject-name', @name)[1]) = 1 and count(key('subject-name', @name)) = 1]">
            <xsl:sort select="@name" />
            <xsl:value-of select="@name" />
        </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```